# Bedikas Chometz - why use a wooden spoon?

Tags: minhag, passover

The [common custom that I am aware of](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47611&pgnum=83) is that a Bedikas Chometz set [has a wooden spoon](http://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/bedikas-chometz-set-NM12301.html). Why do we use a wood spoon by Bedikas Chometz?

Comment: Who's we? I don't.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Then you have clearly not fulfilled _tashbisu_ your entire life.

Comment: @SethJ Oh no!!! You're right in fact: every year as I scoop the chametz into the bag with a metal spoon (not with my hands, of course!) invariably some boiling water falls on the spoon with the chametz, and I never have time to kasher it before Chag; it's always so disappointing! If only I could just burn the spoon with the chametz...

Comment: @DoubleAA Re: burning the spoon, _that_ is why you are supposed to use wood.

Comment: You can use any piece of wood. Why does the spoon have to be wood? In addition a fire can be started with other flammables and does not need wood specifically.

Comment: @SethJ Exactly my guess for the origin of this minhag. But of course, you could also just use your hands; or a metal spoon and rinse it off; or a wooden spoon and rinse it off; or a metal pitchfork and throw it out; etc.

Comment: @GershonGold You're right! It does not need to be wood specifically or a spoon for that matter. If you say one should use a wooden spoon because that is the minhag, then your answer is: because that's what they did in Europe. This fits in nicely for those who still wear fashionable Polish clothing. For the rest of us, I don't see much of a need to use a *wooden* spoon or even a spoon at all.

Comment: There is for sure a valid reason for this Minhag, and hopefully someone will post it.

Comment: @GershonGold I'm not sure what you mean by 'valid', but we will see if you get anything better than my speculation.

Comment: @DoubleAA I use the spoon for kindling. I think at one point in my life I would use the spoon for the first couple of pieces of planted bread crumbs - y'know, to be yotzei - and then just use my fingers. The paper envelope that the kit comes in is also great for that purpose.

Comment: @GershonGold, not to sound too cynical, but why are you not asking about the feather also?

Comment: Ohh, @GershonGold nice find on that Hebrewbooks link! OK, now the question seems legit. But who is the author of that?

Comment: @SethJ, I don't know, but there a lot of hechsherim on the inside cover: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47611&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=

Answer (score 4):

> "Because we need to burn the Chametz the next day we use wood and paper, which are flammable materials."

from [Askmoses.com](http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/199,67426/How-do-I-do-the-Search-for-Chametz-Bedikat-Chametz.html#footnote2)

The website itself does not cite any further source.

[This article on Aish.com](http://www.aish.com/h/pes/l/48969586.html) clearly says that one is not required to use a candle - a flashlight is acceptable.  Since it makes no mention of a spoon at all, one may infer that a spoon is not required either - and certainly not a wooden spoon.

If one can indeed fulfill Bedikas Chametz without a wooden spoon, our questioner is asking, "Why use a wooden spoon?"

That, I can answer in [ONE WORD](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRdfX7ut8gw)...

Answer (score 4):

The Shulchan Aruch haRav writes (OC 445:7)

> ואם לא מצא שום חמץ בבדיקתו טוב לשרוף הכלי שלקח לבדיקה כדי שלא ישכח חובת הביעור לשנה הבאה וגם כדי שלא ישכח לבטל ביטול השני שנתבאר בסי' תל"ד:‏
>   If one didn't find any leaven in his search, it is appropriate to burn the vessel which he search with [the next morning] in order that the process of burning [on Erev Pesach morning] not be forgotten in future years, and also so that one does not forget to nullify [one's leaven] the second time [in the morning].

*Perhaps* one could speculate that those who use wooden spoons do so in case they don't find any leaven and want to burn the spoon the next morning.

Answer (score 3):

A fellow in Shul this morning told me that Rabbi Meir Shapiro ZT'L brings down in the name of the Rashash Mesechtas Shabbos 66 that since per Rabbi Yehuda, Nosar has to be burned with a fire fueled by wood, the Chometz must be burned the same way, with a fire fueled by wood. I asked him that answers the wood part however it still does not explain why it has to be a spoon? Why not a twig or a 2 x 4? He said he saw an answer and does not remember and will let me know. So I will add that part in later.

Comment: This answers for biur not bedika.

Comment: Any updates? |||