# Source for spoon, feather, and candle used in bedikas chometz?

Tags: minhag, names, passover, provenance, bedikas-chametz

What is the original source for the Ashkenazic tradition to do--as is [popularly taught](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/117217/jewish/Search-for-Chametz.htm)--the final search for chometz with a spoon, a feather, and a candle?

It may not have an official source; in that case, what is its earliest mention?

Finally, what are the--presumably Yiddish--words that are/were used for the spoon, the feather, and the candle? (Brown paper bag is extra.)

Comment: Do you mean the Bedikas Chometz Set (http://www.judaica-world.com/bedikas-chometz-set.html)? I always assumed that that was the official name from time immemorial -- "Bedikas Chometz Set."

Comment: I assume feathers are traditionally called "feathers", dustpans are traditionally called "dustpans", and brown paper bags are traditionally called "brown paper bags". Why would anyone call them something else? How do you use a spoon to search for things? I use a spoon to eat things.

Comment: The items that are "traditionally" used have no halachic requirement, from my understanding. The only item specifically mentioned in Shulchan Aruch is "ner", which at that time was most likely a candle. (I supposed, a lit piece of wood would have done the trick, too.) These days, you can use a flashlight from your smart phone to do the job. The spoon, dust pan and feather are not required, and you can just collect the chametz with your hands. I think a better question might be who invented the set with its items to begin with. And, why do some stores advertise this set as being Kosher Lepesah?

Comment: related, somewhat - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15497/5275

Comment: Independent of whether there is a halachic requirement for it, I would like to know the names. This site includes other issues of Judaism than halacha. Also, if it's minhag ashkenaz to use the stuff, then it sorta is halacha

Comment: A parallel minhag to putting out pieces of chametz so that the blessing will not have been in vain, was a minhag to burn the utensils used in the search. This some kind of burning of something was fulfilled. That is the assumed source for using items that burn to conduct the search comes from.

Comment: @user6591 I've heard of this--i.e. with burning nail clippings. The burning is supposed to be some form of making a witness that you did the mitzvah. Do you have a source which mentions a connection between this concept and the spoon/feather/candle? I'd love to see.

Comment: The burning of nails is from the Gemara. It is based on ancient beliefs that they can cause harm. The burning of the searching utensils is brought in the Ramma (IIRC). I can't get up now to check my baby is sleeping on me. But I'll check soon bli nedder. I don't think they are connected.

Comment: SAH the nail burning idea is found in maseches Nida 17a. (Note that burning one's nails also viewed as a health problem, but is a better option than having a pregnant lady step them). The burning of the items used for Bedikas Chametz when no chametz is found is in the Ramma at the end of siman 445. He is quoting a Maharil the exact reason given is 'so as not to forget the requirement to burn'.

Comment: I don't think your last paragraph is very related to the other questions. Do you think the Yiddish names have a special significance? (And anyway, that part might not be on topic here. Also, have you tried [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/yi/Candle%2C%20feather%2C%20and%20spoon%20(and%20a%20brown%20paper%20bag).)?)

Comment: https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/wooden-spoon-for-bedikas-chometz

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol26Ron.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A **chabad.org** article titled "[Why the Spoon and the Feather](https://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/1483403/jewish/Why-the-Spoon-and-Feather.htm)?" addresses this. The reason given for the **candle** is a practical one: so that we can see the bread.

In terms of the spoon and feather:

> We search with a **wooden spoon** so that we can burn it later. We read in the Code of Jewish Law
>   [[SA Orach Chaim 445:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.445.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), see Rama] that if one does not find any leavened foods during his search, he should burn the vessel with which he searched.
>
> This can be easily accomplished with a wooden spoon. Even nowadays, when we put out ten pieces of bread (so we always find something leavened), there is still significance to burning the bread specifically in a wood-fueled fire.
>
> The **feather** serves a practical purpose. We can use it to sweep up any crumbly bits of leavened food that we may encounter.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedikas_chametz) gives another reason for the feather:

> "[a feather is] used throughout the year to 'egg' the challah, and is therefore burnt in the chametz."

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question at all

Comment: @DoubleAA can make that argument for the feather (agree that the answer doesn't give a satifying reason), but the candle (*svara* reason- people need to see) and  the spoon are answered no?

Comment: No, read it again. The question didn't seek reasons for the practice.

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess you're referring to earliest mention. It's sometimes confusing when the question title asks one question, yet the text itself asks an entirely different question

Comment: I don't see the title saying anything different from the text itself. Where does "Source for spoon, feather, and candle used in bedikas chometz?" say anything about reasons?

Answer (score 0):

The burning of the chometz is because you have to "destroy" the leftover chometz that you found or have. You burn the wooden spoon because it provides a source of fuel for the fire. If you used a feather to gather the chometz crumbs, you burn that because it may still have some chometz bits stuck to it. The Chabad.org website gives some of this information.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Aaron!

Comment: I'm not sure this answer the question. It didn't ask about burning hamets.

Comment: The question was about why do we use a spoon feather and candle in bedikas chametz. You answerd about why we burn them with the chametz.